# SQLite Source in Android SDK

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm hoping to get coverage of a test I am running that deals with an SQLiteDatabase, and I specifically want to get the coverage of the underlying C code for SQLite when I run this test. However, I don't know where the location of this C code is in the Android SDK. Can anyone tell me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find it in the folder [`external/sqlite`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sqlite)

Comment: Can you please give me the full path?

Comment: Oh, this is inside the emulator, or android, huh?

Comment: That's in the Android source code, check source.android.com on how to get it

Comment: I have no idea where you are talking about. I have looked in the source code included in the SDK and see no external folder.

Comment: The SDK does not have much source code, only examples. The source for SQLite is part of the Android framework or Android Open Source Project (AOSP). You would need to download that, make the changes you need and recompile to build your own SDK for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not in the Android SDK.  Sqlite is part of the [AOSP](http://source.android.com/source/index.html). There is a browsable mirror here: https://github.com/android/platform_external_sqlite

**EDIT:**
Instead of just trying to build SQLite you could build your own emulator image. You can modify platform/external/sqlite/dist/Android.mk to add the gcov flags.

Comment: Is there a way I can get to this and modify it from command line? I am trying to use the tool gcov and need to be able to get to the directory in command.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/android/platform_external_sqlite.git You could also just build you own emulator image.  Add the -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage to the SQLite Android.mk.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I do have an emulator I can run my tests from and it's from that run that I want to get coverage. Is "fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage" a command run on the emulator?

Comment: Okay, now I know that that command is for the C compiler, but how do I get any physical access to that directory?